# Convergence of power of a convergent sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a monotonically decreasing sequence of positive real numbers such that $a_k \to a$. Then can we say that $a_k^p \to a^p$ for any positive real $p > 1$.

Comment: Not only can you say that, but it happens to be true.

Comment: Yes, very funny. So, somehow you are also saying that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since the functions $x\mapsto x^p$ is continuous. And the fact that the sequence is monotonic doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limit of a product is the product of the limits, provided that each individual factor's limit exists, which you are given as an assumption.

Comment: But here the exponent is real. So can we still apply your result?

Comment: @MittalG, Yes, you can - you may be used to the exponent being an integer, but that is merely a special case.